# How do I estimate volatility for MPR historical data

Tags: volatility, monte-carlo, historical-data, short-rate, jump-diffusion

How can I estimate volatility with historical data for Monetary Policy Rate (MPR) to use in a short rate model?

I could use regular techniques like simple standard deviation or max likelihood, but the problem is the data: MPRs usually have 0 variation over months, even years and then big discrete jumps.

Comment: This will not answer your question, but: Are you bound to use a continuous short rate model? Could a jump model better reflect the observed data?

Comment: I think so. Any recommended model? Any book recommendation to learn about those kind of models?